# Diagram to express parallelism in a process workflow

Tags: architecture, diagrams, parallelism

I'm modelling part of a software architecture on which several processes run as a workflow. The architecture involves data parallelism, where a certain serial process produces N pieces of data which need to be distributed to N processes that must run in parallel.

I'm looking for a good way of expressing parallelism in a diagram. The objective of this diagram is to be informative and will be included in a paper about the system architecture. It does not need to be a formal model or strictly follow UML.

I've drawn 3 ways of representing the parallelism, one of which (2) basically follows the UML 2.0 Activity Diagram. I would like to know which one, if any, will more clearly convey the parallelism. What other information this sort of diagram should include?

[image: Parallelism diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second way you depict not only follows the UML 2.x activity diagram notation but is also used in the [Petri net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net) formal modeling language. Indeed Petri net formalism is the source of UML 2.x activity diagram notation.

Using a Petri-net-like semantic for representing parallelism increases the potential audience who can understand your diagrams.

At the opposite, I read the third way as a choice among several options, just like a state machine.

Finally in my opinion, the first way just looks confuse and amateurish.

Answer (score 2):

If there is standard way to represent something, you should use it.

I suppose that your audience has the minimum of technical knowledge required to understand your document. Therefore, I can reasonably suppose that your audience should have basic knowledge of UML so the diagram should be self-explaining. If you use your own convention you will have to also document it.