# UML how to model parallel activity with runtime-dependent number of participants

Tags: multithreading, uml, concurrency, modeling, parallelism

I want to model an activity that involves processing several items in parallel. So to speak, I want to find a Activity Diagram representation for something like the following snippet / pseudocode:

```
items = findAllReleveantFiles();
handle = threadPool.map(processingFunctionPtr, items);
result = handle.join();
```

I.e. at the time of drawing that diagram I don't know how may files there will be, I just want to signify in some way that parallel processing with a join will happen.

I guess I could model some kind of loop that spawns concurrent processes, like this

[image: Example Loop that is not pretty]

but I don't think this captures the situation nicely and also depends on an imperative processing -- I feel this is too low-level.

In another question ([Diagram to express parallelism in a process workflow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238206/diagram-to-express-parallelism-in-a-process-workflow)), informal representations are suggested already in the question, which I think work in the sense of communicating to the reader of a diagram that parallel processing takes place, but are I think not well-formed UML in the sense of modelling tools like Enterprise Architect.

Comment: Very interesting question ! I wonder if this doesn't have to be represented using an action between a fork and a join, then describing 2 specialization of that action:  a single thread,  and 2 threads, where the second is the same action.